# List of all users in Azure DevOps Organization that have license from the Group Rule

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-devops-rest-api

In Azure DevOps, the users who are assigned license from the group rule and reside in Azure AD. How can we access their user entitlement information. What I want to access is the "lastAccessedDate". When I export the file for users, it only shows the users that have added directly to ADO and are visible in All users list in ADO and the users who got the license via Group Rule cannot be fetch via "Export File" or Rest API. Is there something I am doing wrong or is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access ***user entitlement information*** based on ‘**lastAccessedDate**’ and users having ***license from group rule***, make use of below Rest API call that includes **$filter** and **$orderBy.**

**`GET https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/userentitlements?continuationToken={continuationToken}&select={'Grouprules’}&$filter={(licenseId eq 'Account-Stakeholder' or 'Account-Express') and userType eq 'member'}&$orderBy={lastAccessed desc}&api-version=6.0-preview.3`**

For more information in detail, refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/user-entitlements/search-user-entitlements?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0).

**UPDATE:** As you mentioned in the comment, users need to sign-in **at least once** after assigning licenses to them. Then only you can export the list along with **`lastAccessedDate`**.

Comment: Thanks.
When I ran that command on the browser, it is throwing out an error as below. 
{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Invalid filter: \"{(licenseId eq 'Account-Stakeholder' or 'Account-Express') and userType eq 'member'}\"","typeName":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Exceptions.InvalidQueryStringException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi","typeKey":"InvalidQueryStringException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}

Comment: Hi @VishalThakur, please check the **Rest API version** you are currently using. If it is different from this version **`api-version=6.0-preview.3`** query won't work. Please note that each version supports different set of queries. What version you are currently using??

Comment: Sorry I am not very strong with the coding so I kinda lost it over here.

Comment: This is resolved. The solution was there but is lost in limited information. 
If the question was not clarify, I will explain here again.
When I give access to users via group rules, one of the license(stakeholder, basic or basic + Testplans) was assigned to the user. The problem was if the users don't show up in the all users list I cannot find the last access date for auditing. 
The solution was that once the license was assigned the user wont show in "All users" until the user signs in. Once I can see it in the list I can export the last access date too. 
Thanks for your efforts :-)